# How do I compare 2 different sized 2D arrays?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

The first 2D array is

```
[[1, 10], [0, 4], [1, 1]]
```

The second 2D array is

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [0, 8], [0, 9], [0, 10]]
```

How do I find if they have values overlapping in the 2nd column?
And after finding the overlap, how do I replace the element in the 2nd 2D array with the 1st 2D array?

For example:
`[1, 10]` from the 1st 2D array has the same 2nd column value as `[0, 10]` from the 2nd 2D array. Then, I replace `[0, 10]` with `[1, 10]`.

Comment: Iterate over the first array and add all the "second values" into a set. Then iterate the second array's second values and see if any of these values is already in the set.

Comment: Might also need to consider the case where there's multiple overlaps (both _from_ the first array, _and_ in the second array).  Writing a form of pseudo-code from what you've described will go a long way for you figuring out the solution.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int[][] first = {{1, 10}, {0, 4}, {1, 1}};
    int[][] second = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}, {0, 6}, {0, 7}, {0, 8}, {0, 9}, {0, 10}};

    // first lets build a map for easy lookup of values 
    // produces map {1=1, 4=0, 10=1}
    final Map<Integer, Integer> map = Stream.of(first)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key[1], value -> value[0]));

    // then we can do simple loop
    for (int[] pair : second) {
        // and if it contains the key (second column)
        if (map.containsKey(pair[1])) {
            // then we can just replace the value
            pair[0] = map.get(pair[1]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
  int arr1[][] = {{1, 10}, {0, 4}, {1, 1}};
  for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
  {
    int temp = arr1[i][1];
    if (temp > 0 && temp <= 10)
    {
      arr1[i][0] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Answer (score -1):

If duplicate key found in first 2D array, the last one will override the previous value.
Simple for loop for the beginner of Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] firsts = {{1, 10}, {0, 4}, {1, 1}};
    int[][] seconds = {{0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {0, 4}, {0, 5}, {0, 6}, {0, 7}, {0, 8}, {0, 9}, {0, 10}};

    for(int[] secondRow : seconds) {
        for(int[] firstRow: firsts) {
            if(firstRow[1] == secondRow[1])
                secondRow[0] = firstRow[0];
        }
    }       

    // Use for displaying updated result only
    for(int[] secondRow : seconds)
        System.out.println("[" + secondRow[0] + ", " + secondRow[1] + "]");     

}
```